Is the branding of Brotherhood of Steel Squires by Knights in the Fallout TV series an original addition, or does it draw from existing game lore?
In Season 1 of the 2024 Fallout TV series, there's a scene where Maximus, an Aspirant of the Brotherhood of Steel, undergoes a branding ritual. He receives a brand on the back of his neck from a Brotherhood of Steel Knight, signifying his promotion to Squire.

This ritual is also depicted with Thaddeus, another Squire who is branded with a ‘T’, the initial of his Knight’s name. Now, I've played through some Fallout games, but I don't recall ever coming across any lore or background information about the Brotherhood having this kind of branding ritual.
It’s entirely possible that I’ve overlooked or forgotten some detail hidden in the game’s extensive worldbuilding—a note, a terminal entry, or perhaps a passage in a journal. So, I’m curious: does this depiction of the Brotherhood of Steel Knights branding their Squires have any roots in the lore from the Fallout games? If so, which game first introduced this ritual?

The only reference to this in the Fallout WIKI is sourced from the television show.
Branding does not appear in either of the original Fallout Bibles by Chris Avellone, and to my memory does not appear in any of the games as a BoS initiation rite, either.
